How to identify a date if it is in 1st 2nd 3rd year from another given date in Excel
I am trying to prepare an efficient formula to detect a specific date (Today) if it is in 1st or 2nd or 3rd year from a Start_date.
My expectation is that:

I did try
(Today - Start_date)/365, but it was somehow problem with leap years.
Please help with this. Thanks a lot.

=DATEDIF(A8,$B$8,"Y")+1 will return the number of years between both dates plus one for current date.

Super @Ike, neat and work like charm. Appreciate that.

=ROUNDUP(YEARFRAC(A8,$B$8),0) would work too.
